# My implementation of Bresenham's algorithm fails for lines at certain angles

Tags: python, bresenham

I've written an implementation of Bresenham's algorithm in Python (following the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)), and it works correctly except for lines at certain angles.  All lines that should extend between 45 and 90 degrees, or between 135 and 270 degrees, will instead extend along the line y = x.

Here's my code:

```
def bresenham(origin, dest):
    # debug code
    print origin
    print dest
    # end debug code
    x0 = origin[0]; y0 = origin[1]
    x1 = dest[0]; y1 = dest[1]
    steep = abs(y1 - y0) > abs(x1 - x0)
    backward = x0 > x1

    if steep:
        x0, y0 = y0, x0
        x1, y1 = y1, x1
    if backward:
        x0, x1 = x1, x0
        y0, y1 = y1, y0

    dx = x1 - x0
    dy = abs(y1 - y0)
    error = dx / 2
    y = y0

    if y0 < y1: ystep = 1 
    else: ystep = -1

    result = []
    #if x0 > x1: xstep = -1
    #else: xstep = 1
    # debug code
    print "x0 = %d" % (x0)
    print "x1 = %d" % (x1)
    print "y0 = %d" % (y0)
    print "y1 = %d" % (y1)
    for x in range(x0, x1):
        if steep: result.append((y,x))
        else: result.append((x,y))
        error -= dy
        if error < 0:
            y += ystep
            error += dx 
    # ensure the line extends from the starting point to the destination
    # and not vice-versa
    if backward: result.reverse()
    print result
    return result
```

Anyone see what I'm screwing up?

---

EDIT:

I added some printing code to the function.

(0,0) is at the top left of the display.

My test framework is pretty simple.  It's a standalone function, so I just pass two points to it:

> > > origin = (416, 384)
> > >       dest = (440, 347)
> > >       bresenham(origin, dest)
> > >       (416, 384)
> > >       (440, 347)
> > >       x0 = 384
> > >       x1 = 347
> > >       y0 = 416
> > >       y1 = 440
> > >       []

Comment: @aaa carp:  Nope.  Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: Aside from `if x0 > x1: xstep = -1` being unnecessary, I don't see anything wrong with your code, so your problem is likely to be elsewhere. You'll need to post your actual results so we can see what's happening.

Comment: @Gabe: `xstep` is needed because without it, if `x0 > x1`, then the for loop will terminate immediately, as the default step for a Python for loop is 1.  Aside from that, what kind of results do you want?  When it goes wrong, it returns a list of points where each point is (1,1) above or below what came before it.

Comment: Max: Please post a few sample inputs and the incorrect outputs they produce. You don't need to check for `if x0 > x1` because you swap `x0` and `x1` before that line runs.

Comment: Silly Q: can you show your test framework (my Python-fu is all twisted up) and examples calls of it working and not working (that's just two lines of code).  I don't think the data is crucial.

Comment: Also - which version of Python on which platform?  Did you build it or download it?

Comment: @Gabe: I posted some sample inputs and outputs in a comment in Blaenk's answer.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: I'm using Python 2.6 on Ubuntu 9.10.

Comment: I posted the solution by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you're using an xstep variable. You don't really need one with the algorithm you're using.

> @Gabe: xstep is needed because without it, if x0 > x1, then the for loop will terminate immediately, as the default step for a Python for loop is 1.

The reason you don't need an xstep variable is because, if it's going backwards, the coordinates were already switched (in the `if backward:` conditional at the beginning) so that the end-point is now the start-point and vice-versa, such that we now are *still* going left-to-right.

You just need this:

```
result = []

for x in range(x0, x1):
    if steep: result.append((y, x))
    else: result.append((x, y))
    error -= dy
    if error < 0:
        y += ystep
        error += dx

return result
```

If you want the list of coordinates in order from start to end-point, then you can do the check at the end:

```
if backward: return result.reverse()
else: return result
```

**EDIT**: The problem is that the `backward` boolean is being evaluated *before* it needs to be. If the `steep` conditional executes, then the values change, but by then your `backward` conditional is different. To fix this, instead of using a `backward` boolean, make it an explicit expression:

```
if x0 > x1:
    # swapping here
```

Then again, since you end up using the boolean later on, you could just define it before the conditional:

```
backward = x0 > x1

if backward:
```

Comment: Originally I had it like you were suggesting, but when I tried to make a line in the angles mentioned in my question, the function would return nothing, since the for loop would terminate immediately. `xstep` was a fix for that.  Perhaps that's indicative of something else wrong with my implementation?

Comment: The loop shouldn't fail because remember, we swapped the coordinates such that it's still going from left-to-right (ex. x0, x1 = x1, x0). Perhaps you should print out x0 and x1 before the loop to verify.

Comment: I did, and x0 was indeed greater than x1.

Comment: @Max: your comment here suggests that the range is not set correctly.  Have you printed the x0, x1, y0, y1 values you end up with?  The whole point of the algorithm is that it works with increasing x values.  If x0 > x1 when you do the range, then you'd end up with an empty range - and a quick loop.

Comment: Yeah. Think about it. The conditional at the top checks to see if x0 > x1, and IF IT IS, then it swaps them. So in no way should the loop's range consider that x0 > x1, do you see the disconnect here? Perhaps your swapping isn't working. Do what Jonathan said and print out the values to verify.

Comment: I realized you guys were right after I thought about it a bit.  Something must be more wrong than I thought. Here's some printouts from the algorithm.  origin: (416, 384) dest = (440, 347) x0 = 384, x1 = d47, y0 = 416, y1 = 440.  Does that shed any light on the subject?

Comment: Turns out it was a pretty simple problem that I overlooked. It took me some scratch paper and a pencil to run it through my head to see the problem xD

Comment: Yes, it was fairly obvious once I looked at the test data.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are computing `x0 > x1` before you swap `x` and `y`.

Instead of:

```
backward = x0 > x1 

if steep: 
    x0, y0 = y0, x0 
    x1, y1 = y1, x1 
if backward: 
    x0, x1 = x1, x0 
    y0, y1 = y1, y0
```

You should have:

```
if steep: 
    x0, y0 = y0, x0 
    x1, y1 = y1, x1 

backward = x0 > x1 
if backward: 
    x0, x1 = x1, x0 
    y0, y1 = y1, y0
```

Comment: Guess I don't deserve even a measly upvote for all the work I did, side from the fact I posted the solution before him ;_; Props to Gabe though for spotting it too :)

Comment: @Blaenk.  Sorry, you're right. Got it a whole minute earlier. Fixed, and upvoted to boot.  Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation I am using, which is much faster than pure Python thanks to numba

```
from numba import njit
from typing import Tuple
import numpy as np


@njit
def bresenham_numba(x0, y0, x1, y1, w, h):
    dx = abs(x1 - x0)
    dy = abs(y1 - y0)
    sx = -1 if x0 > x1 else 1
    sy = -1 if y0 > y1 else 1
    err = dx - dy
    points = [(x0, y0)]
    while x0 != x1 or y0 != y1:
        e2 = err * 2
        if e2 > -dy:
            err -= dy
            x0 += sx
        if e2 < dx:
            err += dx
            y0 += sy
        points.append((x0, y0))

    points = [p for p in points if 0 <= p[0] < h and 0 <= p[1] < w]
    return points


def calculate_bresenham(start_point: Tuple[int, int], end_point: Tuple[int, int], resolution: Tuple[int, int]):
    w, h = resolution
    x0, y0 = start_point
    x1, y1 = end_point
    bresenham_list = bresenham_numba(x0, y0, x1, y1, w, h)
    return np.array(bresenham_list)
```